# How to use VIF in r?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret, multicollinearity

I am new in R and learning ml using `caret`. I was working on UCI bank marketing response data but used `iris` data here for reproducibility.

**Issue** is that I am getting `error` on running `vif` from `car package` on `classification` models.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(car)

iris

# to make it binary classification
iris_train <- iris %>% filter(Species %in% c("setosa","versicolor"))
iris_train$Species <- factor(iris_train$Species)
```

**Creating Model**

```
model_iris3 <- train(Species ~ ., 
                      data = iris_train, 
                      method = "gbm",
                     verbose = FALSE
                      # tuneLength = 5,
                      # metric = "Spec", 
                      # trControl = fitCtrl
                      )
```

**Error in vif**

```
# vif
car::vif(model_iris3)
```

> Error in UseMethod("vcov") : no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"

I got to know about using `finalModel` for vif from this SO post: [Variance inflation VIF for glm caret model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251868/variance-inflation-vif-for-glm-caret-model-in-r)

**But still getting an error**

```
car::vif(model_iris3$finalModel)
```

> Error in UseMethod("vcov") : no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "gbm"

same error I get with `adaboost`, `earth` etc.

Appreciate any help or suggestions to solve this issue.

(**UPDATE**)

Finally this worked (see the complete solution in `Answers` if you still get an error):

`vif` doesn't work on `classification` models so convert `dependent` variable to `numeric` and run `linear regression` on it and then `vif`

```
model_iris4 <- train(as.numeric(Species) ~ ., 
                      data = iris_train, 
                      method = "lm",
                     verbose = FALSE
                      # tuneLength = 5,
                      # metric = "Spec", 
                      # trControl = fitCtrl
                      )

car::vif(model_iris4$finalModel)

######## output ##########

Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    4.803414     2.594389    36.246326    25.421395
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`car::vif` is a function that needs to be adapted for each type of model. It works in the linked question because `car::vif` has been implemented to cope with `glm` models. `car::vif` does not support your chosen model type: `gbm`.

Comment: thanks @BrianLang, I was looking more on internet and now I think `car::vif` or in general `vif` doesn't work with `classification` models. For `classification` I will have to change dependent variable into numeric and then create linear regression on it and then run `vif`.

Reference: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_test_multicollinearity_in_binary_logistic_logistic_regression

Comment: Exactly. [Crossvalidated has more information as well.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294678/multicollinearity-between-two-categorical-variables)

Comment: yes, I will update the solution code in the post. Thanks again for helping :)

Comment: If you find the right way to do it, you can always answer your own question! That way when people look in the future they will have your newfound knowledge!

Comment: Sure, I will add the code in the Answer section as well !!

Answer (score 2):

Finally this worked:

`vif` doesn't work on `classification` models so convert `dependent` variable to `numeric` and run `linear regression` on it and then `vif`

```
model_iris4 <- train(as.numeric(Species) ~ ., 
                      data = iris_train, 
                      method = "lm",
                     verbose = FALSE
                      # tuneLength = 5,
                      # metric = "Spec", 
                      # trControl = fitCtrl
                      )

car::vif(model_iris4$finalModel)

######## output ##########

Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
    4.803414     2.594389    36.246326    25.421395
```

There are high chances that if you have dummies in model than it may still give error.

For example: After following above steps I got new error on my original UCI banking dataset: `Error in vif.default(model_vif_check$finalModel) : there are aliased coefficients in the model`

**To solve this error you can try below steps**

run `alias()` on `model` where `predicted` variable is `numeric`

```
alias_res <- alias( 
  lm( as.numeric(y) ~ duration+nr.employed+euribor3m+pdays+emp.var.rate+poutcome.success+month.mar+cons.conf.idx+contact.telephone+contact.cellular+previous+age+cons.price.idx+month.jun+job.retired, data = train ) 
  )

alias_res
```

```
ld.vars <- attributes(alias_res$Complete)$dimnames[[1]]
ld.v
```

this will return an alias that was causing error, so just remove that predictor from the model and run `model` again (in my case it was  `"contact.cellular"`)

```
model_vif_check_aliased <- train(as.numeric(pull(y)) ~ duration+nr.employed+euribor3m+pdays+emp.var.rate+poutcome.success+month.mar+cons.conf.idx+contact.telephone+previous+age+cons.price.idx+month.jun+job.retired, 
                      data = train, 
                      method = "lm"
                      )
model_vif_check_aliased
```

Now run vif

```
vif_values <- car::vif(model_vif_check_aliased$finalModel)
vif_values
```

duration       nr.employed         euribor3m             pdays
1.016706         75.587546         80.930134         10.216410
emp.var.rate  poutcome.success         month.mar     cons.conf.idx
64.542469          9.190354          1.077018          3.972748
contact.telephone          previous               age    cons.price.idx
2.091533          1.850089          1.185461         28.614339
month.jun       job.retired
3.936681          1.198350

Comment: Great Job! You can change your "best answer" flag and select this answer instead of mine since this is the correct best answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks @BrianLang :) , according to SO I can't accept my own answer for 2 days.